# Texture coordinates in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, textures

Sorry for a really noob-level question...

I want to apply a specific piece of the texture (not the entire texture)  to a quad. The texture is a 256x64 image and I'd like to be able to specify the relevant piece by stating the pixel coordinates of its upper-left and bottom-right corners ( [0,0] being the upper left corner of the whole image and [256,64] being the bottom right).

Any ideas on how to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide help on the following query. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188857/draw-texture-in-opengl-android-from-0-0-coordinates

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188857/draw-texture-in-opengl-android-from-0-0-coordinates

Comment: Please provide help on the following query

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188857/draw-texture-in-opengl-android-from-0-0-coordinates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fractional answer is correct, but if you want to use integer texture coordinates (for example in a VBO) you can use the `GL_TEXTURE` matrix to change your texture coordinate system:

```
        glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE)
        glLoadIdentity()
        glScalef(1f/256f, 1f/64f, 1f)
```

After that your texture coordinate units would be pixels.  Another scaling strategy would be to scale so each tile is 1x1 in the final units.

Answer (score 1):

imagine you want to use the 20x20 texel starting at 10,10, you'd use the following coordinates:

```
[10.f/256.f,10.f/64.f]
[30.f/256.f,10.f/64.f]
[30.f/256.f,30.f/64.f]
[10.f/256.f,30.f/64.f]
```

Answer (score 0):

You use float-based texture coordinates, where they range from (0.0f, 0.0f) to (1.0f, 1.0f). In your case, you take your pixel values and divide them by either 256-1 or 64-1, depending on which dimension you are dealing with. (This assumes you really meant to say that your image goes to [255,63] and not [256,64], meaning that your coordinates are 0-based and not 1-based.)

Comment: no, there is never a -1. Reason is, 0.f corresponds to the left of the first texel, 1.f corresponds to the right of the last one.

Comment: Yeah, but from his OP, it's not clear whether his texel positions are 0-based or 1-based. If they are 0-based, and we divide by width (or height), you will never get 1.0f.

Comment: Even then, it would change the offset, not the divider. if the texture is 256 wide, the divider will always be 256.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the following, simplified example of 1D texture of 8 pixels width (the pixel centers are at the digits):

```
 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
```

The corresponding texture coordinates are:

```
 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
0/8 1/8 2/8 3/8 4/8 5/8 6/8 7/8 8/8
```

Now if you want the subtexture from texels 3 to 7 the texture coordinates to use are 2/8 to 7/8.

You should also take note about something else: Integer texture coordinates don't address texel centers, but the exact mid between them; this may cause a blurred appearance in certain situations.