# draw texture in OpenGL Android from 0,0 coordinates

Tags: android, opengl-es, coordinates, textures, vertices

I'm new to opengGL and excuse if the questions are too naive. I'm going through some tuturials for seeking help on learning this. I have a small program written where i'm drawing a texture on a GLSurfaceView.

I want to draw a number of textures(bitmap images) in a sequential order starting from 0,0 coordinates. Also I need some gap in images on the screen. Please help. Do I need to change the positioning of vertices buffer. please suggest.

Here is my renderer Code.

```
public class GlRenderer implements Renderer{

    private Square  square; // square1
    private Context context;

    /** Constructor to set the handed over context */
    public GlRenderer(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

        // initialise the square
        this.square = new Square();
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        // clear Screen and Depth Buffer
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Reset the Modelview Matrix
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        // Drawing
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);     // move 5 units INTO the screen
        square.draw(gl);                        // Draw the triangle
        //gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);        // move 5 units INTO the screen
        //square2.draw(gl);                     // Draw the triangle
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        if(height == 0) {                       //Prevent A Divide By Zero By
            height = 1;                         //Making Height Equal One
        }

        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);     //Reset The Current Viewport
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_TEXTURE);   //Select The Projection Matrix
        gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Projection Matrix

        //Calculate The Aspect Ratio Of The Window
        GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float)width / (float)height, 0.1f, 100.0f);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);     //Select The Modelview Matrix
        gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Modelview Matrix
    }

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        // Load the texture for the square
        square.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context);

        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);            //Enable Texture Mapping ( NEW )
        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);            //Enable Smooth Shading
        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);    //Black Background
        gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);                     //Depth Buffer Setup
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);            //Enables Depth Testing
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);             //The Type Of Depth Testing To Do

        //Really Nice Perspective Calculations
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST); 

    }
}
```

Here is the square code

```
public class Square {
    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;   // buffer holding the vertices
    private float vertices[] = {
            -1.0f, -.25f,  0.0f,    // V1 - bottom left
            -1.0f, .25f,  0.0f,     // V2 - top left
            1.0f, -.25f,  0.0f,     // V3 - bottom right
            1.0f, .25f,  0.0f       // V4 - top right
    };

    private FloatBuffer textureBuffer;  // buffer holding the texture coordinates
    private float texture[] = {         
            // Mapping coordinates for the vertices
            0.0f, 1.0f,     // top left     (V2)
            0.0f, 0.0f,     // bottom left  (V1)
            1.0f, 1.0f,     // top right    (V4)
            1.0f, 0.0f      // bottom right (V3)
    };

    /** The texture pointer */
    private int[] textures = new int[1];

    public Square() {
        // a float has 4 bytes so we allocate for each coordinate 4 bytes
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        // allocates the memory from the byte buffer
        vertexBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();

        // fill the vertexBuffer with the vertices
        vertexBuffer.put(vertices);

        // set the cursor position to the beginning of the buffer
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texture.length * 4);
        byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        textureBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
        textureBuffer.put(texture);
        textureBuffer.position(0);
    }

    /**
     * Load the texture for the square
     * @param gl
     * @param context
     */
    public void loadGLTexture(GL10 gl, Context context) {
        // loading texture
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                R.drawable.progressbar_bg);

        // generate one texture pointer
        gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
        // ...and bind it to our array
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

        // create nearest filtered texture
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

        //Different possible texture parameters, e.g. GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
        //      gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
        //      gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);

        // Use Android GLUtils to specify a two-dimensional texture image from our bitmap 
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

        // Clean up
        bitmap.recycle();
    }


    /** The draw method for the square with the GL context */
    public void draw(GL10 gl) {
        // bind the previously generated texture
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

        // Point to our buffers
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        // Set the face rotation
        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);

        // Point to our vertex buffer
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);

        // Draw the vertices as triangle strip
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertices.length / 3);

        //Disable the client state before leaving
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    }
}
```

I am not able to see the actual size of texture on the view. I was playing with gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f); to manipulate the coordinates of texture on screen. But still not able to get the actual image size and position the texture image at desired loaction starting from 0,0 coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by using glTranslate() properly. Now I understand that translate takes the last translated value of the surface for its current position. I have made the changes for that now with fixed x and z coordinates and y changing after each draw of texture. I did the following:

```
        float x = -1.0f;
    float y = 1.5f;
    float z = -5.0f;

    // Drawing
    gl.glTranslatef(x, y, z);
    square1.draw(gl);                       // Draw the square
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, -0.50f, 0.0f);
    square2.draw(gl);                       // Draw the square
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, -0.50f, 0.0f);
    square2.draw(gl);                       // Draw the square
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, -0.50f, 0.0f);
    square2.draw(gl);                       // Draw the square
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is confusion between the drawing objects and drawing bitmaps (Pixel operations)

From you requirements "I want to draw a number of textures(bitmap images) in a sequential order starting from 0,0 coordinates. Also I need some gap in images on the screen. Please help. Do I need to change the positioning of vertices buffer".
It is preferreed that you should draw bitmaps. Refer to api glBitmap, glDrawPixels, etc etc

For textures. The concept/approach you applied is correct.  You are drawing a rectangle between (-1,-1) and (1,1). The texture is mapping seems correct. However, you need to play around withe api for
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT Or CLAMP);
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT );
(PS-PLease use android based apis appropriately)

When you experiment with glTranslatef, the object also moves (along with the texture).

Imagine you are drawing shirt, with a pattern. The pattern coordinates are with respect to the shirt. Use the texture apis to position the pattern on the shirt.
And the translatef calls moves the world coordinate system but the pattern will not change.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have taken this example to draw an image on the screen using this approach. I want to draw with the actual coordinates for the screen. most f the example tells how to draw an image on the center of the screen with 0,0 coordinates as center.

Comment: Can you help in making me understand on how to take the drawing coordinates starting from 0,0 position i.e. top of the screen. pleae provide references through code i have shared so that it become easy to undertand

Comment: If you are using the pixel draw functions (where in you are drawing directly to the screen buffer) use apis such glPixelZoom. You can use negative values to change direction. However, If you are trying to use model transformations use glRotate API. Use a combination of translation and rotation.

Comment: Reference : The opengl red book.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the pixel draw functions (where in you are drawing directly to the screen buffer) use apis such glPixelZoom. You can use negative values to change direction

If you are trying to use model transformations use glRotate API. Use a combination of translation and rotation.